# How to give pointer in JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

I have one json object and one array as follows:

```
a = [{"id":1,"content":"aaa"},{"id":2,"content":"bbb"}];
b = ["a.jpg","b.jpg"];
```

Now i want to create one more json object which points to this json and array ,
Something like :

```
c = [{groupId:1,
      "group":[{"aId":pointer to a json,"bId":pointer to b array
              },{"aId":pointer to a json,"bId":pointer to b array
              }]
    }];
```

Is it possible in javascript??

Comment: Are you really talking of JSON (that is the string encoded version of the objects) or of JS objects ? In the first case it's impossible, in the second case it's easy.

Comment: It looks to me like you have two arrays. One array contains two objects, the other array contains two strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot do that (have pointers or references in [JSON](http://www.json.org/) notation).

You may define your own *convention*, such (for example), that a JSON object like `{"refId": 1}` means *to your applications* to be some "pointer" to the thing decoded with the JSON `"id":1` but you have to code for that.

FWIW, the [YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) notation has references (with [anchors](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#anchor) and [aliases](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#alias//))

Answer (score 5):

There is a *proposed standard* [RFC 6901: JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) Pointer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901), which introduces a concept of a pointer in JSON structure.

Here is an example taken from the RFC:

> For example, given the JSON document
>
> ```
> {
>   "foo": ["bar", "baz"],
>   "": 0,
>   "a/b": 1,
>   "c%d": 2,
>   "e^f": 3,
>   "g|h": 4,
>   "i\\j": 5,
>   "k\"l": 6,
>   " ": 7,
>   "m~n": 8    }
> ```
>
> The following JSON strings evaluate to the accompanying values:
>
> ```
> ""           // the whole document
> "/foo"       ["bar", "baz"]
> "/foo/0"     "bar"
> "/"          0
> "/a~1b"      1
> "/c%d"       2
> "/e^f"       3
> "/g|h"       4
> "/i\\j"      5
> "/k\"l"      6
> "/ "         7
> "/m~0n"      8
> ```

There are also some packages available that support this RFC, like [json-pointer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-pointer).

Answer (score 4):

Theoretically it would be possible, but as soon as you send the json to a different machine, the pointers would be invalid.

You have 2 possibilities to solve the problem:

1. nest the array and the json in the original json
2. reference the array and json by some sort of ID. This second
   approach need more work on both the sending and receiving side, but
   reduces the amount of space used by your json.